# Build a grid and let the squares blink

Tags: java, jframe

I'm not well familiar with Java and try to build a grid in a window but I'm not sure which Class I should extend (like JFrame) and which method is the best way to get that grid.

My goal is to create a grid and let the squares blink randomly.

I tried it JPanel but not sure if it is the right way

JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));

Comment: Well, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with Java, Swing, and JavaFX. Try going through the tutorials/trails, do some simple demos, etc. Then come back to this

Comment: Hint: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: Please don't try to add information about your question in the comments.  Instead, edit your question to make it better, and add any additional information to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a JPanel on a JFrame. You override the paintComponent Method of the JPanel to fit your needs:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    //draw rects
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        //draw rects
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    //fill rects
    for(int i=0; i<n i++){
        //set random color for blinking effect
        g2d.setColor(/*random color*/);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

You have to compute the grid yourself though, using the size of your JPanel and the size of the squares you want to draw.
Then, set a Timer and redraw every time you want that blinking effect.

If you are not familiar with java Swing and simple draw operations, you should watch same tutorials etc. because im not going to explain it all here ;).